# How to execute SQL from Oracle SQL Plus passing variable name SQL file from Unix

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, hp-ux

For Oracle DB and HP-UX :
I have a variable name SQL file like:  `my_sql_file_${TIMESTAMP}.sql`

I assign this file to a variable:  `MYSQLFILE="my_sql_file_${TIMESTAMP}.sql"`

So, I am trying to execute the MYSQLFILE inside SQL Plus, like:

```
@${MYSQLFILE}
```

but this appears that it cannot be done.
Is there any way to achieve the above??

Thank you.

Comment: Can you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54310766/edit) to show how you're calling SQL\*Plus and using the variable in context? Changing sensitive data of course (username/password/etc.) but otherwise leaving it exactly as you run it?

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
MYSQLFILE="my_sql_file_${TIMESTAMP}.sql"

sqlplus -S user/password@db << EOF
@$MYSQLFILE
exit;
EOF
```

You can also pass user, password and db as parameters to your script

Comment: Unfortunately, I have already tried that and does not work... :(     I get response:  SP2-3010: unable to open file "$MYSQLFILE".

Comment: @Kostas75 - are you doing it exactly like this, or are you perhaps quoting the heredoc marker - i.e. `<< "EOF"` ?

Comment: I am doing exactly like this (with the EOF) and does not work, tried several times. Only the 1 line command works  (with no EOF).

Comment: @Kostas75 Which shell are you using?

Comment: @vc 74:  #!/bin/sh  (inside shell script) at HP-UX.

Comment: @Kostas75 Can you try with bash?

Comment: Weird, this seems to work: http://tpcg.io/7ZXWmO
Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: @vc 74:  Yes, same error response that I have mentioned above (for shell script):  SP2-3010: unable to open file "$MYSQLFILE".

Comment: What happens if you echo the variable instead of sending it to sqlplus?

Answer (score 2):

you can use

```
sqlplus user/pass@service_name @$MYSQLFILE
```

inside SQLPLUS, you can also use

```
sql> host echo $MYSQLFILE
```

And this is also valid,

```
sqlplus user/password@db <<EOF
  @$MYSQLFILE
  exit;
EOF
```

Comment: The 1-line command works fine:  sqlplus user/pass@service_name @$MYSQLFILE.   The EOF is exactly what I have tried to do when I opened this questions here and does NOT work, at least not at my environment.

Comment: Glad that you solved your problem. If you believe that this answer is useful for you please consider to upvote and/or mark it as answer so that community can also benefit from it :) thank you

Comment: Problem solved with different approach, question was not answered exactly, but OK.

Comment: If there is another approach can you please share your practice with us?  besides I am not meaning check my post as an answer, but if you think any of them relevant to your problem you should mark it as answer. This is how community works and This is how we share out know how

Comment: OK, basically I used the 1-line sqlplus call, but also had to include the sets, commit and quit at the SQL file, because everything should be done from within the SQL file, since I could not use the EOF  (it does not work at my system).

Comment: so you used same approach which I had described? you just changed inside of your SQL file.